# Automorphism of a non-abelian finite group sending 3/4 of elements to inverses

Tags: abstract-algebra

Taken  From Topic in ALgebra  herstein, Page No .71, question No.12

can you find an example of a finite group which is
non-abelian and which has an automorphism which maps exactly
three-quarters of the elements of G onto their inverses?

My attempts  : my professor said  me That take  $\mathbb{Q_8}$(Quaternion group).

i take $T= \begin{bmatrix} 1 &-1&i&-i&j&-j&k&-k \\ 1& -1&-i&i&-j&j&k&-k \end{bmatrix}$

Now  How  can i show  that $ T $ is an  auto morphism of $\mathbb{Q}$ which transfer exactly $\frac{3}{4}$ element of $\mathbb{Q}$ into their  inverse

Pliz  help  me,,,

thanks u

Comment: That title is rather misleading.

Comment: okk@LordSharktheUnknown..then  what  title i have to put

Comment: "How can i show that $T$ is ..." $\leftarrow$ what is $T$?

Comment: @Théophile..i have  edits,......see the post one more

Comment: Well, you can see that $T$ maps exactly $3/4$ of the elements onto their inverses. Now prove that $T$ is an automorphism.

Comment: That certainly maps six elements to their inverses, but is it an automorphism? Could it be an inner automorphism say?

Answer (score 1):

An automorphism is an isomorphism $T:G\to G$. I.e. An isomorphism to itself. You explicitly defined a permutation of elements so it is certainly a bijection.

It therefore suffices to show that $T$ is a homomorphism. This is rather awkward if you want to check it directly. (Because you have a lot of combinations to check.)

It is somewhat easier if you define what happens to the generating elements and extend the map to a homomorphism and check that they satisfy the given relations.

I.e $Q_8=\langle i,j,k: i^4=j^4=k^4=1, ij=k, jk=i, ki=j\rangle $ And define $T(I), T(j), T(k)$ and show they satisfy the given relations.